# I cannot write a WAV file from scipy despite confirming dtype=ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSoT1.png)
I am trying to concatenate many audio files into one with scipy but cannot.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.io.wavfile import write, read
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("MusicData/") if isfile(join("MusicData/", f))]

big_music = np.concatenate(np.zeros((1,2)))

i = 0
for file in onlyfiles:
    i += 1
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(i)
    if "-converted" in file:
        x = scipy.io.wavfile.read(f"MusicData/{file}")
        big_music = np.concatenate([big_music, x])


test_out = scipy.io.wavfile.write("big_music.wav", 44100, np.array(big_music))
```

I am trying to normalize many audio files to  between 0 and 1 in one big file in order to train a GAN.

Edit: this is the error:
`ValueError: Unsupported data type 'object'`

Edit 2:
Here is another error I receive after assuring that in fact I am dealing with an object with the appropriate interface:
[Error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pH2e.png)

Comment: Examine `bigmusic`.  type?  shape? dtype?  Error says it isn't a numeric array

Comment: Type is ndarray!

Comment: and the rest of my question?

Comment: Could you clarify?

Comment: Please look closely at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html). You presumably want to `np.concatenate` only the `data` chunks, and do something else with the `rate` data that is also returned.

Comment: I read the docs carefully and that solved the dtype error but I am now running into this when attempting to handle the data alone: IndexError: tuple index out of range